# How do I position a div directly below it's sibling ( without using fixed coordinates )?

Tags: css

I've got the following html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="pageHeader">
      <h1><span>Page Title</span></h1>
    </div>

    <div id="navigation_menu">
      <ul>
        <li id="treeslink"><a href="#">Trees</a></li>
        <li id="gardenslink"><a href="#">Gardens</a></li>
        <li id="portlink"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

I want to put `navigation_menu` directly beneath the `pageHeader`.

So I have this in my .css:

```
#container {width:870px; margin:0 auto;position:relative;}

#pageHeader h1 
{
  position:absolute;
  width:870px;  
  margin-top:0;
  font:74px "F25_TypewriterCondensed";
  letter-spacing:-2px;
}

#navigation_menu
{
  position:absolute;
  width: 169px;
}
```

But the navigation_menu just appears over `pageHeader`, at the top left corner of `container`. Is it possible to get it just underneath?

Comment: If you can set a height on #pageHeader then you can position the menu below it fairly easily.

Comment: @j08691 - setting a height didn't work, it resulted in no change.

Comment: do you need navigation_menu to be absolutely positioned?  This seems like a funny choice if you want it t naturally appear under the header.

Comment: Well no, that alone wont work. Then set a margin-top on the navigation to equal the height you just set on the header.

Comment: @Sandy, no i don't need it to be absolute. But I did that because a tutorial I was following said to position all elements with `absolute`, if they are within a container and you want them all to be position relative to the container.

Comment: @j08691 - that worked thanks! Don't really understand it though.

Comment: OK I'll post it as an answer and explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you use the absolute positioning. What you are after is actualy default behaviour. I updated your css to this:

```
#container 
{
   width:870px; 
   margin:0 auto;
}

#pageHeader h1 
{

  margin-top:0;
  font:74px "F25_TypewriterCondensed";
  letter-spacing:-2px;
}

#navigation_menu
{
  width: 169px;
}​
```

check the fiddle to see the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ebgVq/

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems, first, get rid of absolute positioning on `navigation_menu`, it will make it ignore the "pushiness" of the other divs above it.

Second, we have to make pageHeader get pushed.  When you make an element positioned absolutely it loses it's ability to make other objects flow around it, including parent elements which want to re-size to their content.  Having an absolutely positioned `h1` inside of that `div` makes the `div` size to 1px x 1px.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a height on `#pageHeader h1` and then set a margin-top on `#navigation_menu` using the same amount (e.g. 100px each) this should accomplish what you want. Since you're positioning absolutely you take the elements out of the flow of the document. By giving the header a height, you can then position the menu below it explicitly by bumping it down by the same amount. It's really a visual effect only since both elements are out of the flow.